# Linux does only recognizes 1 of 2 cameras on USB HUB

Tags: linux, usb, camera

i have a 10 Port USB hub connected to my ODroid N2 running Ubuntu. On that hub i have a set of devices, among them are 2 similar camera systems.

What is happening is, that on boot only one camera is detected and shown in lshw and the other is not. When i unplug the "unrecognized" one and replug it in, it is recognized and i have 2 cameras.

I noticed that both have the same serial. Does that mean the second is not detected because Linux thinks it registered it already. Is that even possible?

**Any help to recognize both cameras at boot time is much appreciated.**

BEFORE UNPLUG

```
 *-usb:1
        description: USB hub
        product: USB3.2 Hub
        vendor: GenesysLogic
        physical id: 4
        bus info: usb@2:1.2.4
        version: 93.07
        capabilities: usb-3.20
        configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
      *-usb
           description: Video
           product: PayCam
           vendor: RYS, Inc.
           physical id: 2
           bus info: usb@2:1.2.4.2
           version: 0.01
           serial: 00000001
           capabilities: usb-3.00
           configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=800mA speed=5000Mbit/s
```

AFTER UNPLUG

```
   *-usb:1
        description: USB hub
        product: USB3.2 Hub
        vendor: GenesysLogic
        physical id: 4
        bus info: usb@2:1.2.4
        version: 93.07
        capabilities: usb-3.20
        configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
      *-usb:0
           description: Video
           product: PayCam
           vendor: RYS, Inc.
           physical id: 2
           bus info: usb@2:1.2.4.2
           version: 0.01
           serial: 00000001
           capabilities: usb-3.00
           configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=800mA speed=5000Mbit/s
      *-usb:1
           description: Video
           product: PayCam
           vendor: RYS, Inc.
           physical id: 3
           bus info: usb@2:1.2.4.3
           version: 0.01
           serial: 00000001
           capabilities: usb-3.00
           configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=800mA speed=5000Mbit/s
```

Camera (https://astar.ai/pages/calicam)
USB hub(https://www.exsys-shop.de/shopware/en/categories/usb-products/503/10-port-usb-3.2-gen-1-metal-hub-with-15kv-esd-surge-protection-a-ports)

Comment: If it is aviable, can you plug the second camera on a USB port directly on your machine, not on a hub?

Comment: Systematically debug this: (1) Does the same happen with both cameras directly plugged in? If not, it's related to the hub. (2) Does the same happen with a different hub (if you have one)? If not, it's a problem with that particular hub, probably nothing you can do about it.  (3) Do you get the same problem with both camers plugged in, and hub unplugged and re-plugged? If yes, makes it easier to debug. (4) Use Wireshark on the USB ports and see if there's a difference in messages when the hub is used.

Comment: it is the same when plugging both into the odroid. And also if one is on the odroid and one on the hub. So due to that I guess it is a linux thing

Comment: This hub seems to have an optional power supply.  Do you have an external power supply connected to it, and what are its ratings amp,volts?

Comment: It has a 24v supply that can supply up to 60A (there are a few other things connected to iot, but at time of testing nothing is drawing energy). @dirkt do you think that reinitializing the USB after boot can help, I read something about restating udev. But have no idea how to do it properly.

Comment: If it's the same when plugging in both devices directly, remove the hub from the picture (motto: simplify to debug). Next step is to look at `dmesg` both with 2 plugged in and one re-plugged in. If that doesn't give clues, it's time for Wireshark. Resetting udev likely is not going to help if the problem is that both cameras with same serial prevent the second from being recognized in some kernel layer. And if both are in the hub, even resetting USB (not udev) won't help.

Comment: I have a second unit with the same hardware/software setup. On this one, both cameras are being recognized. Even though both have the same serial. I will dmesg and see if there is anything at boot-time that shows the problem